# PHP: concatenate possible combinations from an array

Tags: php, loops, combinations

I have an array with sets/groups of strings in different combinations (in this example lower and upper case). I am trying to loop this array - using php - and generate new strings concatenated from all possible combinations that the original strings can make up.

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ALFA
            [1] => alfa
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BETA
            [1] => beta
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DELTA
            [1] => delta
        )
)
```

The out put I would like to have should be like this:

```
ALFA
ALFA BETA
ALFA beta
ALFA DELTA
ALFA delta
ALFA BETA DELTA
ALFA BETA delta
ALFA beta beta
ALFA DELTA BETA
ALFA DELTA beta
ALFA delta BETA
ALFA delta beta
alfa 
alfa BETA
alfa beta
alfa DELTA
alfa delta
alfa BETA DELTA
alfa BETA delta
alfa beta beta
alfa DELTA BETA
alfa DELTA beta
alfa delta BETA
alfa delta beta
BETA
BETA ALFA
BETA alfa
BETA DELTA
BETA delta
BETA ALFA delta
BETA ALFA DELTA
BETA alfa delta
BETA alfa DELTA
BETA DELTA alfa
BETA DELTA ALFA
BETA delta alfa
BETA delta ALFA
beta
beta ALFA
...
...
```

I have spent the whole day trying to figure this out, but are stuck. Any input or help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's a very simple problem and the solution is straight-forward, but let me ask you *why* are you trying to do this? There is almost certainly a better way of doing what you're trying to accomplish in this very low-performant and high-memory manner.

Comment: How long did it take you type up the expected output and complete, by hand, what you wanted your script to do automatically?

Comment: @Mahmoud: What I am trying to accomplish is a script that takes 1-4 input strings and generate a word list with all possible combinations of these words. Each input string will also be in different format, such as upper case, lower case, upper first, upper last etc.

Comment: You misunderstood - what's the *big picture* that having all the different combinations of strings will help with?

Comment: I want to make a word list with "qualified guessed" passwords, so I can try to brute force a WPA router.

Answer (score 0):

you could store an array containing only the lower-case version of those strings, and then dynamically capitalize it ([strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) does the job).

Then with nested `for` loops or with recursion you go through each element of the array and `echo` the various combinations you need (just skip the cases where you are on the same element in two layers of iteration (or recursion))

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi, it seems an odd problem and could easily knacker your server if the array is larger than trivial size. You do realize that we are talking about factorials here - if your array has 10 elements, the number of permutations with all 10 strings in one case alone would be 10! which is 3.5 millions Add the upper and lower case version, add the combinations of strings with 9, 8, etc elements and we are talking about very long calculations. After 10 element array, every extra one multiplies the number of calculations by at least 10, i.e. 35 millions with 11, 350 millions with 12... you get the drift.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
class CartesianProductIterator implements Iterator {
    protected $iterators;

    function __construct(array $iters) {
        $this->iterators = $iters;
    }

    function rewind() {
        foreach ($this->iterators as $it) {
            $it->rewind();
        }
    }

    function current() {
        $values = array();
        foreach ($this->iterators as $it) {
            $values[] = $it->current();
        }
        return $values;
    }

    function key() {
        return null;
    }

    function next() {
        /*      
        loop them in reverse, but exclude first
        why? example, odometer: 55199
        you always check the rightmost digit first to see if incrementing it would roll it over and need to be "rewound" to 0, 
        which causes the digit to the left to increase as well, which may also cause it to roll over as well, and so on...
        looping in reverse operates from right column to the left.
        we dont rewind the first column because if the leftmost column is on its last element and needs to roll over
        then this iterator has reached its end, and so rewind() needs to be explicitly called 
        */
        for ($i = count($this->iterators) - 1; $i > 0; --$i) {
            $it = $this->iterators[$i];
            $it->next();
            if ($it->valid()) {
                // were done advancing because we found a column that didnt roll over
                return;
            } else {
                $it->rewind();
            }
        }

        //if execution reached here, then all of the columns have rolled over, so we must attempt to roll over the left most column
        $this->iterators[0]->next();
    }

    function valid() {
        return $this->iterators[0]->valid();
    }
}
```

you could specialize its use as follows

```
$iterators = array();
foreach ($arr as $possibleChoicesForOneSlotInACombo) {
    //we add null as a way indicate "no value" as a choice for this slot
    $possibleChoicesForOneSlotInACombo[] = null;
    $iterators[] = new ArrayIterator($possibleChoicesForOneSlotInACombo);
}

foreach (new CartesianProductIterator($iterators) as $combo) {
    //filter out the possible nulls that might exist in this combo
    $strings = array_filter($combo, 'is_string');

    // make sure something exists, maybe they were all null
    if ($strings) {
        echo join(' ', $strings), "\n";
    }
}
```